# Can I play Borderlands 2 on PC with a controller?

Tags: pc, borderlands-2

I have recently bought the game on Steam.  When i plugged a USB game controller into my PC.  I booted up my game.  However, steam states it can be played with a controller but in menu options there is no ability to key bind my controller.  What is up with this?

Comment: What controller are you using?

Comment: Gravis Gamepad Pro

Comment: Seems like this controller is not natively supported. You could try it with x360ce controller emulation. Here's a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejKZbE1GCOo)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, you can.

On the [Borderlands 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/49520/) page on Steam it says "Full controller support" meaning that it **will** be compatible with a Xbox 360 controller or any other controller that works with PC and is supported by Steam.

However, as far as I can see your controller is not supported. But @5pike's solution to use [x360ce](https://github.com/x360ce/x360ce) should work.

Comment: Funny it says full controller support yet i cant use mine.